Angular velocity of an object in expanding universe
In flat FRW metric, the physical momentum of an object in free motion is inverse proportional to the scale factor, that is
\begin{align}
P_{phy} \propto 1/a
\end{align}
where $a$ is a scale factor.
Now, let's consider the object with fixed physical size. The object is rotating with initial angular velocity $\omega_0$.(Suppose that the situation is non-relativistic.)
The question is

Does the angular velocity decreases as the universe expands; i.e. scale factor $a$ increases?
If it does, what would be the relation between angular velocity and scale factor?
ex) $\omega(t)=\omega_0 \frac{a(t)}{a_0}$

